# Does vsize give the correct result for number?

Tags: oracle

When I create a table as

```
Create Table e_det(eno Number, ename Varchar2(20), sal Number);
```

I inserted

```
eno as 111
ename as jone
sal as 2000
```

`vsize(ename)` returns `4` because name is 4 characters.

`vsize(sal);` returns `2`.

Can you explain this?

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](http://download-east.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions213.htm):

> *VSIZE* returns the number of **bytes** in the internal representation of *expr*.

If you want the number of characters instead, try

```
Length( To_Char( sal ) )
```

instead.

Comment: If you do `select dump(2000) from dual;`, you see the two bytes are 194 and 21